# What does Islam says about the praying of crippled person?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, islamic-philosophy, contradiction

In our daily life there are a number of people who have health issues and some are also disabled. They are having difficulties in walking, sitting or in some cases standing. As a Muslim we know that there is no coercion in our Religion. Our Religion gave those people a concession in every aspect as they can pray according to their condition. But my question is : 
Is it permissible to those people to use a chair during praying the prayer and prostrate but their head not touch the earth? 
 If any one can briefly explain

Comment: You've answered your question already: one may pray in a manner that eases oneself, as long as one is not able to pray in a better manner so take also a look at [How am I supposed to pray if I'm having terrible headaches](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-am-i-supposed-to-pray-when-im-having-terrible-headaches) and [Clothing and praying ettiquette for disabled woman](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38201/clothing-and-praying-ettiquette-for-disabled-woman)

Answer (score -2):

[Read this Fatwah on IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/71202/how-can-a-person-who-is-partially-paralyzed-do-wudoo-and-pray)

فَاتَّقُوا اللَّهَ مَا اسْتَطَعْتُمْ وَاسْمَعُوا وَأَطِيعُوا وَأَنفِقُوا خَيْرًا لِّأَنفُسِكُمْ ۗ وَمَن يُوقَ شُحَّ نَفْسِهِ فَأُولَٰئِكَ هُمُ الْمُفْلِحُونَ 
Al-Taghabun|16